# how to show an image in unity by code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using unity and I want to show an image of "game over" in my 2D unity project when the game has finished.
For example I have a counter in my code from 0; when the counter reaches 3, the game will be over and you will lose. But I don't know how to show the Game Over Message.This message is a picture.
and I want to add a "Play Again" button, after showing the game over message.
How can I do these?

Comment: Please use the correct tag for this, which is Unity3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int counter = 0;
GameObject gameOver;

public void IncreaseCounterBy(float amt)
{
    counter += amt;
    gameOver.SetActive(counter >= 3 && gameOverPanel != null);
}
```

or

```
int counter = 0;

public void IncreaseCounterBy(float amt)
{
    counter += amt;
    if(counter >= 3)
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add an object with the image and the button, then disable the object using the inspector and when your counter reach 3 the you can activate the object by code..

something like:

```
public GameObject gameOverPanel;
int counter = 0;
public void YourCounterCode()
{
//here's your code
  if(counter >= 3 && gameOverPanel != null)
    gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
}
```

that should be enough for your purpose

Comment: forgot to mention.. you should disable again the object (gameOverPanel) by code when pressing the "Play Again" button unless you restart the whole scene

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have a reference of your game over GameObject in your game controller (the code of the game). This gameObject should be marked as deactivated by default.

Second, when the game is over, or the player lost, you should call a method to "wait" and show the GameObject. This method should be a coroutine if you think in your counter as a time counter.

```
public GameObject myGameOverGO;

public void GameEnds()
{
   //....
   StartCoroutine( DisplayGameOver() ) 
   //....
}

private IEnumerator DisplayGameOver()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);

   myGameOverGO.SetActive(true);
}
```